# What are some good resources to learn Remote Code execution

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

I want to learn remote code execution from scratch. Is there any sort of book where I can learn from, or there is a preunderstanding required to learn remote code execution? I am desperate to learn remote code execution because I heard in pwn2own and remote code execution is most exploited technique used.

Comment: Remote code execution is the result of another problem in the code or the configuration of the server. I'm afraid that there is no "book" to read, because it is a symptom, not the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to learn about how it happens, and why, in multiple languages. Why? After a while, you'll notice a pattern, and find that several techniques are portable.

1. [Buffer Overflow](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_Overflows)

   - Stack Buffer Overflow
   - Heap Buffer Overflow
2. [PHP `eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
3. [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)
4. Reading about Remote Code Execution / [Code Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection) on OWASP.
5. [Googling "remote code execution"](http://google.com/search?q=remote%20code%20execution)